# Sending a BufferedImage of webcam in a Socket

Tags: java, sockets, video, webcam, jmyron

I'm trying to send a video captured by a webcam from a server to a client.

I'm using Jmyron in netbeans to get the camera.

First, I used `BufferedImage.toString()` and tried to send the string I was getting over a socket. I also tried to turn the `BufferedImage` into a byte array and send it so I can do the reverse process in the other side. 
It seems that the Socket is sending one line and then stopping.
So could you tell me if there is another way to do this. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong ?

Also is RTP available in Jmyron? Because I want to send the video in real time.

I'm sending this from the server : 
    BufferedImage captureImage

```
    boolean Test= true;
        while (Test) {
        ServerSocket ser = new ServerSocket(25000);
        Socket sock = ser.accept();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ImageIO.write( captureImage, "jpg", baos );
         baos.flush();
         byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
         baos.close(); 

         DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
         dOut.write(imageInByte);

      }
```

receiving from the client :

boolean Test = true ;

```
public Clientcam() throws IOException {
    initComponents();

   while (Test) { 

          Socket ser = new Socket("localhost",25000);

          byte[] b = null ;  
        DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(ser.getInputStream());
        dIn.readFully(b);
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
        newImage = ImageIO.read(in);
        newlbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(newImage));

    }

}
```

Comment: The `toString` mechanism is not going to work. How did you turn the `BufferedImage` into a `byte[]`? Did you try using ImageIO to write the buffered image as say a jpeg over the socket output stream?

Comment: "Real time" could be anything depending on your definition of real time ... anyway, for us to help you, it is neccessary to show some of your code. From what you write I guess yes,  you are in fact doing sth wrong. But without code it is impossible to tell exactly what.

Comment: Hi @BrettOkken, thnx for replying. I have edited my text and put some of my code , could you take a look at it please !

Comment: Hi @Fildor  thnx for replying. I have edited my text and put some of my code , could you take a look at it please !

Comment: Is this not throwing an NPE at client?